# Rails 3 query specific data from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling

Here are my two models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :values
end

class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :account
end
```

On my account model I have a :name attribute and a :type attribute where I choose either 'checking' or 'savings'. Every quarter of the year I record an amount for each account, this goes on the value model. The value model has a :quarter attribute (either 1, 2, 3, or 4), a :year attribute, and an :amount attribute. Some accounts get updated for every quarter of the year, and some don't. So for example I could have a checking account that has values for the 1,2,3,and 4th quarters of 2010, and then another checking account with values for only the 1st and 2nd quarters. Every time a quarter is entered, it is just an update of the previous quarter, not a running cumulative total.

What I want to do is to run a query that will show me my average account value for last year for a certain account type, 'checking' or 'savings'. The thing I'm struggling with is that I can't just run a query and total the whole year, because only the last entered value (ordered by :quarter and :year) is the actual value, not a total of all the quarters. So how do I loop through all of the 'checking' accounts for example and pull the :amount from most recently entered value entry, whether that was the 1st quarter or the 4th?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the created_at timestamp of the `value` record to order the results. It sounds like you want the most recent value record within a given range. If you can't order the results by date can you simply order by `:quarter DESC` and use the first result?

Don't forget about utilizing AVG() functions on the SQL server side: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Also check out http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: kind of. Say for example I have 4 checking accounts, one account had 1st quarter, another 1st and 2nd, another 1st, 2nd, and 3rd, and the last had all 4 quarters entered. I want to average the value across all 4 checking accounts based on the last entry for each account. So in this example it would be all different quarters. Does that make more sense?